# 3 digit generator in C

Tags: c, numbers, printf, putchar

I'm trying to generate every possible 3-digit combination like: `012, 013 ,014...`

**BUT:** I want to ignore repeated characters **(like 999 or 022)** and I also don't want to re-use numbers **(if 123 already there, don't display 321)** so, the last value should be **789.**

Here My code :

```
int main()
 {
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=1;i<(1<<9);i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
            if ((1<<j)&i) printf("%d\n",j+1);
        }
    }
 }
```

I want my result to be ordered like:

```
012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019, 023, ..., 789
```

Also, I'm not supposed to use any function **but printf / putchar**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way to solve this would be something like

```
for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
{
    for (j = i+1; j <= 8; j++)
    {
        for (k = j+1; k <= 9; k++)
        {
            printf("%d%d%d\n", i, j, k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: EXACTLY what i wanted !
Previous code was working too but unordered, thanks to both of you guys.

Comment: Another question !
How could i use putchar insted of printf ?

Comment: `putchar` interprets its argument as an ASCII character - thus, if i equals 7, `putchar(i)` will not print the character '7', but the character with the ASCII code 7, ie. the 'BELL' character. To get the correct output, you have to find where the digits 0-9 are located on the ASCII table. It turns out that '0' is ASCII 48, and the other digits conveniently follow in the right order, so `putchar(i+48)` will give you the desired result.

Comment: @UlrichSchmidt-Goertz Or `putchar(i+'0')`, making the intent immediately obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Hello are you from EPITECH ? this is one of the 3rd day of "piscine" work
The difficulty of this function is that you cant use printf neither "my_put_nbr" (%d printf)a function that you will have to code tomorrow i guess and who can print int variable
so you have to find a way to print each character for each number with my_putchar func
for those wondering here is the my_putchar func

```
void my_putchar(char c)
{
write(1, &c, 1);
}
```